# Docker: how to clone container and its data into a new one

Tags: jenkins, docker

Is there a way to clone a container and its data into a new one with different starting parameters?

At the moment I'm only able to start a new cloned container (from custom image) WITHOUT the data.

I tell you what I have to do: I started a "docker-jenkins" container with some starting parameters and then configured it, but now I noticed that I forgot some important starting parameters so I wanna restart the same container adding more starting parameters...

The problem is (if I understand well) that I cannot modify the starting parameters of existing running container, so my idea is to start a cloned one (data INCLUDED) with different parameters but I don't understand how to do it...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**1. Using volumes**

If your sole point is to persist your data you need to use Volumes.

> A data volume is a specially-designated directory within one or more
>   containers that bypasses the Union File System. Data volumes provide
>   several useful features for persistent or shared data:
>
> - Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point,
>     that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume
>     initialization. (Note that this does not apply when mounting a host
>     directory.)
> - Data volumes can be shared and reused among containers.
> - Changes to a data volume are made directly.
> - Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image.
> - Data volumes persist even if the container itself is deleted.

Source:

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

Essentially you map a folder from your machine to one into your container. 
When you kill the container and spawn a new instance (with modified parameters) your volume (with the existing data) is re-mapped.

Example:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Source:

> https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

---

**2. Using commit to create snapshots**

A different route is to make use of the docker commit command.

> It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings into
>   a new image. This allows you debug a container by running an
>   interactive shell, or to export a working dataset to another server.
>   Generally, it is better to use Dockerfiles to manage your images in a
>   documented and maintainable way.
>
> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes
>   mounted inside the container.
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

```
$ docker ps
ID                  IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
c3f279d17e0a        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours
197387f1b436        ubuntu:12.04        /bin/bash           7 days ago          Up 25 hours
$ docker commit c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version3
f5283438590d
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 ID                  CREATED             SIZE
svendowideit/testimage            version3            f5283438590d        16 seconds ago      335.7 MB
```

It is also possible to commit with altered configuration:

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["apachectl", "-DFOREGROUND"]' -c "EXPOSE 80" c3f279d17e0a  svendowideit/testimage:version4
```

Comment: Exactly! What I wanna do is to run a new cloned container with "-v" parameter (volumes) and "--privileged" to grant more privileges to jenkins user but the problem is that the new "cloned" container has not the data of the original one. The snapshot I created doesn't contain the data... how can I create a snapshot with data included?

Comment: Sharing volumes is not a replication. Because the 2 containers share the same data. Any data change to one container will affect the other.

Answer (score 3):

To clone a container in docker, you can use docker commit and create a snapshot the container

Use `docker images` to view the docker image **REPOSITORY** and **TAG** names.
Use `docker ps -a` to view the available containers and note the **CONTAINER ID** of the container of which a snapshot is to be created.

use `docker commit <CONTAINER ID> <REPOSITORY>:<TAG>` to create snapshot and save it as an image.
Again use `docker images` to view the saved image.

To access saved snapshot
run,

```
docker run -i -t <IMAGE ID> /bin/bash
docker ps -a
docker start <CONTAINER ID>
docker exec -ti <CONTAINER ID> bash
```